# Parsing XML Data in XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a XML file like the following:

```
<Adresses> 
    <Address1>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLine1</XPath>
      <Key>1</Key>
    </Address1>
    <Address2>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[002]/AddressLine1</XPath>
      <Key>2</Key>
    </Address2>
    <Address3>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[003]/AddressLine1</XPath>
      <Key>3</Key>
    </Address3>
    <Address4>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[004]/AddressLine1</XPath>
      <Key>4</Key>
    </Address4>
    <Address5>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[005]/AddressLine1</XPath>
      <Key>5</Key>
    </Address5>
</Adresses>
```

I want to use XPath in C# to parse the XML values. In this case I want to replace Local[002],Local[003], Local[004] and Local[005] with Local[001] on  element `<XPath>`.

Comment: What *part* of what you are trying to accomplish is causing difficulty?

Comment: What do you want to replace them with?

Comment: I want to replace Local[002],Local[003], Local[004] and Local[005] with Local[001]. Also made a mistake in posting the XML. After Local[00X] portion it should be /AddressLine1, /AddressLine2, /AddressLine3 , /AddressLine4,and /AddressLine5 respectively which will remain same. @Reddog

Comment: The XML is <Adresses><Address1><XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLine1</XPath><Key>1</Key></Address1> <Address2> <XPath>//Address/Local[002]/AddressLine2</XPath> <Key>2</Key> </Address2><Address3> <XPath>//Address/Local[003]/AddressLine3</XPath> <Key>3</Key> </Address3><Address4> <XPath>//Address/Local[004]/AddressLine4</XPath> <Key>4</Key> </Address4><Address5><XPath>//Address/Local[005]/AddressLine5</XPath><Key>5</Key></Address5></Adresses> . I am trying to replcae Local[002], [Local003], [Local004], and [Local005] to Local[001]. Rest of those lines should be same.@Reddog, @Quintin Robinson

Comment: I did this :         if (xpath.Contains("//Address"))
            {   const string LOCAL = "//Address/XPath";
                XmlDocument lDoc = new XmlDocument();
                if (!dr.IsNull("document"))
                {   lDoc.LoadXml(dr["document"].ToString());
                    XmlNodeList localNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes(LOCAL);
                    if (localNodes != null)
                    { xpath = xpath.Replace( @"Local[\d{3}]", "Local[001]");
                        
                    }

                }

            }

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to do this easily.

Here's a very quick example I threw together:

```
var xml = @"<Adresses> 
    <Address1>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[00X]/AddressLine1</XPath>
      <Key>1</Key>
    </Address1>
    <Address2>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[00X]/AddressLine2</XPath>
      <Key>2</Key>
    </Address2>
    <Address3>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[00X]/AddressLine3</XPath>
      <Key>3</Key>
    </Address3>
    <Address4>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[00X]/AddressLine4</XPath>
      <Key>4</Key>
    </Address4>
    <Address5>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[00X]/AddressLine5</XPath>
      <Key>5</Key>
    </Address5>
</Adresses> ";
Console.WriteLine(xml);
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach(var elem in xDoc.Descendants("XPath")){
  var key = Convert.ToInt32((elem.NextNode as XElement).Value);
  elem.Value = string.Format("//Address/Local[{0}]/AddressLine{1}",key.ToString("000"),key);
}
Console.WriteLine(xDoc.ToString());
```

Comment: Acually, the XPath Element values are diffreent except Local portion. It's my honest mistake.I don't want to replace the whole line in that element. Only want to update the Local[00X] portion with Local[001]. Thanks @brendan.

Comment: Not sure I can follow your exact question, updated answer should be close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not quite clear.  AFAIK, XPATH will only take you so far since it is only used for navigating through your XML document.  You can use it to help you find the elements you want but you'll need something else to do the actual replacements.

Using LINQ to XML (in conjunction with regular expressions):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\path\to\file.xml");
var xpath = "/Adresses/*/XPath";
var query = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
foreach (var element in query)
{
    var newValue = Regex.Replace(element.Value, @"Local\[\d{3}\]", "Local[001]");
    element.Value = newValue;
}
```

Using XSLT might be an option but I'm not sure how to use it here in this case. But I bet it wouldn't be pretty (compared to the above code).

Comment: The XML is <Adresses><Address1><XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLine1</XPath><Key>1</Key></‌​Address1> <Address2> <XPath>//Address/Local[002]/AddressLine2</XPath> <Key>2</Key> </Address2><Address3> <XPath>//Address/Local[003]/AddressLine3</XPath> <Key>3</Key> </Address3><Address4> <XPath>//Address/Local[004]/AddressLine4</XPath> <Key>4</Key> </Address4><Address5><XPath>//Address/Local[005]/AddressLine5</XPath><Key>5</Key></‌​Address5></Adresses> . I am trying to replcae Local[002], [Local003], [Local004], and [Local005] to Local[001]. Rest of those lines should be same.@Jeff Mercado

Comment: I did this:         if (xpath.Contains("//Address"))
            {   const string LOCAL = "//Address/XPath";
                XmlDocument lDoc = new XmlDocument();
                if (!dr.IsNull("document"))
                {  lDoc.LoadXml(dr["document"].ToString());
                    XmlNodeList localNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes(LOCAL);
                 if (localNodes != null)
                    {                           
                        xpath = xpath.Replace( @"Local[\d{3}]", "Local[001]");
                        
                    }

                }

            }

Comment: What exactly are you trying to tell me?  The code I've shown here should do it all...

Comment: I was not able to replace. So, I used the code mentioned in my comments. But still not working. Please, help me here. Thanks!

Comment: How were you "not able to replace?"  Like I said... the code I've shown you here should do it all... did you even try it?  If you did, what part about it did not work?  It _will_ work with the XML that you have shown us in the question and in your comments.